# Is there always a worse algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

Is the following true?

> Given a problem with a known algorithm of time complexity $g(n), \exists$ another algorithm to solve said problem with time complexity $f(n). \,\,\, f(n): g(n) = o(f(n)) $

If true, it implies that:

1. For all problems, there are algorithms of arbitrarily high
   complexity that can solve it.
2. For all problems, the number of distinct algorithms that can solve it is infinite.
3. It is always possible to do worse (implicit in $1$).

Comment: You might want to explore some inefficient sorting algorithms. A good place to start would be Wikipedia's [Bogosort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort) entry.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: This isn't an exercise problem. On principle, I don't ask exercise problems,  unless I post my failed attempt first. If I ever ask a question without posting a solution, it is always because I had a hypothesis, and I'm trying to outsource the verification of my hypothesis to the stack exchange network. I think you should be more charitable when interpreting my questions. I didn't get stuck anywhere--I'm just not good at proving hypotheses, and so generally ask questions to verify my hypothesis or receive a counter example.

Answer (score 6):

Given any algorithm $A$, the algorithm "run $A$ $n$ times" has asymptotically worse running time.

Comment: Does this mean that for every problem, of which the fastest known algorithm is in complexity class $X, \, \exists$ an algorithm of complexity class $Y$, where $Y$ is any complexity class with asymptotically worse complexity than $X$?

Comment: @TobiAlafin Think about it yourself, for a bit: it's not a hard question. (As a technical level, note that complexity classes are classes of _problems_, not classes of algorithms. But that point about terminology doesn't affect your underlying question.)

Comment: Consider the ackermann function, or other non primitive recursive functions, or even a function that would he the solution to an algorithm in $ALL$. I'm not sure we can invent an algorithm to do that, short of "run this algorithm of complexity $Y$ on an entirely different problem whose input size is $n$, then run algorithm of $X$", but I think that has problems. Where does the auxiliary problem and it's inputs come from?

Comment: @TobiAlafin "run $A$ $\mathrm{Ackermann}(n,n)$ times" etc.